# Alternative to deprecated gtk_alignment_new

Tags: gtk3

I used the GtkAlignment widget to control the alignment and size of its child widget. But `gtk_alignment_new` has been deprecated since version 3.14 and should not be used in newly-written code. What functions should I use as alternatives to let the code be gtk3+ compatible?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *halign;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tooltip");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button, "Button widget");

  halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), button);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), halign);  

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: from [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html#gtk-alignment-new): Use GtkWidget alignment and margin properties. That is: `halign, valign, hexpand, vexpand, margin*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, use these two functions instead:

- `void gtk_widget_set_halign (GtkWidget *widget, GtkAlign align);`
  Sets the horizontal alignment of widget.
- `gtk_widget_get_valign (GtkWidget *widget);` Sets the vertical alignment of widget.

The enum GtkAlign types are the following:

- `GTK_ALIGN_START`: The 'start' of the layout. Vertically this is the top, horizontally this is left/right according to LTR/RTL
- `GTK_ALIGN_END`: Opposite of GTK_ALIGN_START
- `GTK_ALIGN_CENTER`: The middle of the layout
- `GTK_ALIGN_FILL` : Take all available space

for scaling use `GTK_ALIGN_FILL`.

So the gtk3+ compatible alternative for your code is the following:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;    

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tooltip");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button, "Button widget");

  gtk_widget_set_halign (button, GTK_ALIGN_START);
  gtk_widget_set_valign (button, GTK_ALIGN_START);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```